# Configuration of OpenId Connect token expiration in CAS

Tags: openid-connect, cas

I'm looking for properties to set expiration time of OpenId Connect token. Default is 8 hours, but I want to change it. How can I do that?

I'm using CAS 6.5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Token expiration policy is the same as your SSO session policy in CAS 6.5.x. To change the default to use 2 hours would be, i.e.,  `cas.ticket.tgt.primary.max-time-to-live-in-seconds=7200`. This will make the ID token last for 2 hours, and your SSO session would also last for 2 hours.